# Getting parameter from macro in umbraco 6 via razor

Tags: html, razor, parameters, umbraco

Im having trouble doing this. what i have is this macro:

```
<umbraco:Macro Alias="testingparameter" 
MyOwnParameter="hello" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

So what im trying to do is to get the hello string via my razor script:
I have tried these things:

```
<div>test1: @Parameter.MyOwnParameter</div>
<div>test2: @(Html.Raw(Parameter.MyOwnParameter))</div>
<div>test3: @Model.Parameters.MyOwnParameter</div>
```

But it all returns empty string. what i get back is this

```
 <div>test1:</div>
 <div>test2:</div>
 <div>test3:</div>
```

so I guess none of the above is right, or am I just missing something?

Please note that im using umbraco 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the parameter in the macro within the backoffice too, with an alias of "myOwnParameter". See here for the documentation:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/Templating/Macros/Razor/using-macro-parameters

Also, I recommend using camel case wherever you reference the alias, as I seem to remember that when accessing the parameter through the dynamic `@Parameter` collection, this is how the alias is defined.

Comment: thank you. so what i forgot was to add the parameter in the macro properties. thought it was enough just to add it manually. thank you :-)